# How to find if my *ngFor returns empty?

Tags: angular

I have the following code:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let art of artefacts; let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="art.isSelected == true" fxLayout="row" class="selected-artefacts">
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

I find all items in **artefacts** and display if they have a property `isSelected == true`. Now if there is no element in artefacts that has isSelected = true, I need to display "No items to display". How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 18):

If you use a pipe to filter (for example `| filter`) then you can use it like:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of artefacts">{{item.name}} 
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.isSelected" (ngModelChange)="tick = tick+1">
</div>

<hr>

<ng-container *ngIf="artefacts | isSelected:tick as result; else noItems">
<!-- else is to cover the case where "artefacts" is "null" or "undefined" -->

    <div *ngFor="let item of result; let i = index" fxLayout="row" 
        class="selected-artefacts">{{item.name}}</div>

    <!-- the case where the pipe returns an empty array  -->
    <ng-container *ngIf="!result.length" [ngTemplateOutlet]="noItems"></ng-container>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #noItems>no Items</ng-template>
```

[**StackBlitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j6zwuz)

`as` was added in https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-rc4-2017-03-17

Comment: If the array is empty, the code inside of the ng-container will never be executed right? So I think that the "no items" will never appears. The condition needs to be outside of the loop.

Comment: You're right. That's a silly answer. Switching ngIf and ngFor might work. I'll have another look when I'm on the computer

Comment: @Poney thanks for pointing out my mistake. I updated the answer and added a life example.

Comment: You can also make your filter pipe returns null when result size is 0 or chain an additional pipe that returns null if array length is 0. This way you don't need the second `<ng-container *ngIf="!result.length" [ngTemplateOutlet]="noItems"></ng-container>`

Answer (score 9):

An alternative way to avoid IF/ELSE for this scenario uses CSS only, and it works in any framework (Angular, React, Vue, ...)

```
.no-item:not(:first-child) {
display:none;
}
```

Simply wrap the list with any tag (section, div, ul, ...) and add a last item with the message you want to display and add the class above.

Find a working example here: https://codepen.io/cacothi/pen/vYEJxKR

Comment: This is a very cool workaround when I have to do filtering on the DOM instead of the array itself!

Answer (score 5):

You can simply have an `*ngIf` condition after the loop.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let art of artefacts; let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="art.isSelected == true" fxLayout="row" class="selected-artefacts">
  </div>
</ng-container>
<!-- here -->
<div *ngIf="!artefacts || hasNoSelectedArtefacts()">
   No items to display
</div>
```

Have a function in your component side which checks the array:

```
hasNoSelectedArtefacts(){
  return artefacts.filter(art => art.isSelected).length===0;
}
```

`Array.prototype.filter` can be used to check if there are any items with `isSelected`.

Comment: I run into an error: `compiler.es5.js:1689 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 23 in [artefacts.filter(art => !art.isSelected).length==0]`

Answer (score 1):

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let art of artefacts; let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="art.isSelected" fxLayout="row" class="selected-artefacts">
    <!-- Content -->
  </div>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="noneSelected">
  <!-- none selected -->
</ng-container>
```

In your controller

```
this.noneSelected = this.artefacts.filter(a => a.isSelected).length;
```

Comment: This says "no content" if there's no data in "artefacts" whereas I do not want that. I want to show when there is no item in artefacts that has isSelected = true. For example, `artefacts = [{isSelected : false},{isSelected : false},{isSelected : false}]` should also return "no content" for me.

Comment: @trichetriche just a tip: ternary operator here is redundant..you can just do `this.noneSelected = this.artefacts.filter(a => a.isSelected).length === 0`

Answer (score -2):

Doing this on my phone so text only answer.

The way to do this is to check if your array length is 0. If so then bound a css property to text that says the message you want to say.

Easy

Comment: Just to let you know, Swiftkey keyboard gives the quotes to make code answers on stack !